# Robust ANOVA t2way unequal sample sizes?

Tags: anova, unbalanced-classes, normality-assumption, robust, two-way

I have some parameters that I would like to analyze with a two-way ANOVA. The treatment groups have unequal sample sizes (n=9, n=36, n=36, n=36) and the data do not fulfill the requirement of normal residuals due to several outliers (data transformation therefore doesn't work either).

Is robust ANOVA like WRS2/t2way robust to unequal sample sizes? Or are there better ways to analyze non-normal data with unequal sample sizes?

Thank you very much!